# Magical Record saveWithBlock: not saving

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm having trouble getting my objects to save using the method [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:completion].  When I switch over to using normal blocks it works fine. Using version 2.2develop.

The code below works, and I have commented out the saveWithBlock: specific parts.  The executeBlock...: methods just wrap dispatch_async and executeBlockOnMainThread: replaces the completion: block.

```
[card.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
//[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) { // Replace this...
[NSObject executeBlockInBackground:^{ // With this...

    Card *localCard = [card MR_inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]]; // MR_inContext:localContext];
    NSRange range = [localCard.fragment rangeOfString:localCard.term options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (range.location == NSNotFound){
        return;
    }

    NSString *fragmentString = [localCard.fragment stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.lingq.com/api/languages/%@/phrases/?word=%@&frag=%@&start=%@", appDelegate.currentLanguage, localCard.term, fragmentString, @(range.location)];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [LQAPI requestForURL:url body:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSData *response = [LQAPI executeURLRequest:request];

    NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [LQAPI dictionaryFromJSONData:response];
    if (responseDictionary == nil){
        return;
    }

    NSArray *phrases = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"phrases"];
    NSMutableArray *cards = [NSMutableArray array];
    int index = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *d in phrases){
        Card *c = [self cardFromDictionary:d content_id:localCard.content_Id index:index type:BlueCard];
        c.parentID = localCard.mId; // This marks it as a phrase
        [cards addObject:c];
        index++;
    }
    [localCard.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait]; // This shouldn't be necessary using saveWithBlock: and it didn't help when I tried it.
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentID = %@", localCard.mId];
    NSArray *phrases2 = [Card MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate]; // All the objects appear fine here
    [NSObject executeBlockOnMainThread:^{ // This would have been in the completion block below
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentID = %@", card.mId];
        NSArray *phrases = [Card MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate]; // This does find phrases
        [delegate didFetchPhrases:phrases forCard:card];
    }];
}];
/*   completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentID = %@", card.mId];
 NSArray *phrases = [Card MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate]; // This doesn't find any phrases
 [delegate didFetchPhrases:phrases forCard:card];
 }];*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, it was my fault (Of course!).  The method cardFromDictionary: was using MR_contextForCurrentThread.  Passing it localContext solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

On Github I found that fetching while saveWithBlock: is a no go: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/339

Comment: That's good to know, Volker.  However, is it an issue to fetch within the completion block?  The first fetch (phrases2) is just there for debugging purposes, to show those objects did in fact get created.  The second one in completion: is the important one.